# Unable to lookup JNDI name in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, jndi

While deploying a webapp on weblogic I am encountering the below error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/PassmarkToolDB]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp.env.jdbc.PassmarkToolDB in /app/webapp/wscredentialmanager/1012163426.; remaining name '/comp/env/jdbc/PassmarkToolDB'
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1180)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:143)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:253)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
        at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.AbstractURLContext.lookup(AbstractURLContext.java:135)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
        ... 97 more
```

Can someone please let me know what are the ways to debug this.

Comment: Have you created datasource in weblogic ? As here :  http://www.deltalounge.net/wpress/2011/02/create-data-source-in-weblogic-server/

Answer (score 0):

Did you take look at JNDI Tree in Admin Console?

On Weblogic12c, I'm pretty sure that the JNDI URL is `jdbc/PassmarkToolDB` and not `java:comp/env/jdbc/PassmarkToolDB`